# State transformation for non-holonomic differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, transformation

Given a non-holonomic dynamical system,
\begin{align*}
\dot x = v\cos\theta \\
\dot y = v\sin\theta \\
\dot \theta = \omega
\end{align*} with constraints $|v| < v_{max}, |\omega| < \omega_{max}$, how can we apply a transformation to this system such that in the new coordinates $(x',y',\theta')$ and with a new time scale $\hat{t}$,
\begin{align*}
\dot x' = v'\cos\theta' \\
\dot y' = v'\sin\theta' \\
\dot \theta' = \omega'
\end{align*} with constraints $|v'| <1, |\omega'| < 1$ ?

The non-holonomic dynamics makes the transformation very non-intuitive.

Comment: Should this be only the state transformation? Because the transformation $x \mapsto \alpha x'$, $y \mapsto \beta y'$, $t \mapsto \gamma \hat{t}$ and $\theta \mapsto \theta'$ does job well (for appropriate choice of constants).

Comment: Thanks for the comment! The transformation becomes clear if we allow modification of the time-scale as well.

Comment: I also want to bring your attention to the folowing fact. Although you can choose different values of parameters $v$ and $\omega$, the systems are essentially the same: using the same kind of transformation you can establish equivalence of trajectories of system with any $(v, \omega)$ and system with, for example, $(v, \omega) = (1, 1)$. It doesn't really help here, because the dynamics is not really complicated, but this method (it's called _nondimensionalization_ ) really might help you reduce the dimension of parameter space.

Answer (score 2):

If we employ a transformation of the form 
$x' = \frac{\omega_{max}}{v_{max}}x$ , $y' = \frac{\omega_{max}}{v_{max}}y$, $\theta' = \theta$, $\hat{t} = \omega_{max}t$, then the required form is achieved.